# IsEnable Property of my control not binding in xaml

Tags: silverlight

My dependency property not binded in control.

```
  public bool EnableMe
            {
                get { return (bool)GetValue(EnableMeProperty); }
                set { SetValue(EnableMeProperty, value); }
            }

            public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableMeProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("EnableMe", typeof(bool), typeof(OwnwrClasss), new PropertyMetadata(null));



<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Source=EnableMe}" >
    <Image Source="/Images/icon.png" x:Name="btnShow"/>
<Button>
```

I want to enable and disable this button dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
after setting DataContext of that page.